# Is there a name for dominant-intraspecific competition?

Tags: ecology, terminology, population-dynamics

Some ecological competition dynamics have particular names *(e.g.: scramble competition, contest competition, ...)*. I wonder if there's such a name for competition dynamics where the interspecific interaction is weaker than the intraspecific one.

By weaker I mean that the non-diagonal elements of the community matrix are lower than the diagonal ones.